# Replace parts of a string in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr, sqldf

I would like to be able to replace in the input below the `keywordN` by `tiab LIKE '%keywordN%'` to be able to translate the keyword input into an SQL string in R. Keywords are words or combinations of words for example: `((ELISA) OR (antibody test) AND (blood))`

```
input = "((keyword1) OR (keyword2) AND (keyword3))"
```

to:

```
output = "((tiab LIKE '%keyword1%') OR (tiab LIKE '%keyword2%') AND (tiab like '%keyword3%'))"
```

to be used like this:

```
sqlDF = sqldf(paste("select * from df1 where ",output))
```

Any suggestion? Much appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating your "input" ?

Comment: `input` is passed from a query input in a shiny app. We ask users to use syntax (ie: brackets around groups of keywords)

Comment: And it is always the same column? How about the "AND"  "OR" conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(input, "keyword(\\d)", "tiab LIKE '%keyword\\1%'")

# "((tiab LIKE '%keyword1%') OR (tiab LIKE '%keyword2%') AND (tiab LIKE '%keyword3%'))"
```

For your other example:

```
input <- "((ELISA) OR (antibody test) AND (blood))"

str_replace_all(input, "\\(([^\\(\\)]+)\\)", "(tiab LIKE '%\\1%')")

# "((tiab LIKE '%ELISA%') OR (tiab LIKE '%antibody test%') AND (tiab LIKE '%blood%'))"
```

Comment: Dear Bas,Thanks. However, I would like to have a generalizable solution that would also work for `((ELISA) OR (antibody test) AND (blood))` for example. I updated the question to be more explicit.

Comment: Excellent Bas. Thanks for saving me quite some time! en een fijne dag!

Answer (score 3):

The sqldf package loads the gsubfn package for this purpose so no additional packages are needed.  Also the `paste` used in the `sqldf` statement shown in the question is not needed because gsubfn provides `fn$` for this purpose as used below.

gsubfn matches the regular expression, passes the capture group(s) to the second argument (which is a function that is optionally expressed in formula notation as we do here) and replaces the match with the function's output. We have assumed that keywords consist of letters and numbers and spaces so we have used the character class [A-Za-z0-9 ] to define the valid characters in a keyword but if they can contain other characters add those in.

Below we get an error only because the question did not define a sample `DF` but it still shows the expanded SQL statement passed to the backend so we can see that it worked.

```
library(sqldf)  # sqldf also load gsubfn
input <- "((ELISA) OR (antibody test) AND (blood))"

output <- gsubfn("\\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)\\)", ~ sprintf("(tiab LIKE '%%%s%%')", x), input) 

fn$sqldf("select * from DF where $output", verbose = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
sqldf: library(RSQLite)
sqldf: m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
sqldf: connection <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
sqldf: initExtension(connection)
sqldf: dbGetQuery(connection, 'select * from DF where ((tiab LIKE '%ELISA%') OR (tiab LIKE '%antibody test%') AND (tiab LIKE '%blood%'))')
Error: no such table: DF
sqldf: dbDisconnect(connection)
```

Comment: Just noticed comment under other question regarding a particular example so modified code to be able to handle that.

Comment: Thank you for this addition. I thought it would be the quickest solution to do a keyword search option in R, that allows booleans and nesting. Seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```r
s <- "((ELISA) OR (antibody test) AND (blood))"
gsub("(?<=\\()([^()]*)(?=\\))", "tiab LIKE '%\\1%'", s, perl=T)
# [1] "((tiab LIKE '%ELISA%') OR (tiab LIKE '%antibody test%') AND (tiab LIKE '%blood%'))"
```